# Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED] when creating a service in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, service

I attached the code of the AndroidManifest.xml. I can't figure out what is going wrong. When I comment the line   everything is working ok,(without the service) but when the line is readded I receive the error that I described in the title.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.grkoan.androidbasicsdemo" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SecondActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_second" >
    </activity>
    <service android:name="Services.MyServices" />
</application>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
<service android:name="Services.MyServices" />
```

It should be

```
<service android:name=".MyServices" />
```